# TcpListener: How to listen on specific port on all interfaces?

Tags: .net, sockets, tcplistener, socketserver

There are three overloads for constructing a [`TcpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsyxy9k2.aspx):

- [`public TcpListener(int port);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y2a362e.aspx) (*obsolete*)
- [`public TcpListener(IPEndPoint localEP)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4zw1w3a.aspx)
- [`public TcpListener(IPAddress localaddr, int port)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6z86e63.aspx)

i *want* to listen on a particular port, but on **all** available interfaces. There *was* an overload available to do that, but it's been marked as `obsolete`.

What is the new preferred/non-obsolete way to listen on a particular port on all interfaces with a [`TcpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsyxy9k2.aspx) in .NET?

---

For helpfulness sake, an [`IPEndPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx) is:

```
public IPEndPoint(
    IPAddress address,
    int port
)
```

which is what the 3rd overload is. And an [`IPAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.address.aspx) takes, as its constructor:

- a `byte[]`
- an `Int64`
- a `byte[]` and an `Int64`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just bind to the [`IPAddress.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx) - that's how this is usually done... not sure but it could be that you need to bind to [`IPAddress.IPv6Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.ipv6any.aspx) too.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507254/tcplistener-listen-on-every-address-including-gprs-ip-address/507277#507277) suggests that you bind to every IP addresse explicitly - and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436778/send-broadcast-message-from-all-network-adapters/436898#436898) has code on how to get all IP adresses...

---

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6z86e63%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> If you do not care which local address is assigned, specify `IPAddress.Any` for the localaddr parameter, and the underlying service provider will assign the most appropriate network address.

---

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx):

*IPAddress.Any* Field

> Provides an IP address indicating that the server should listen for client activity on **all** network interfaces.

Comment: Jesus; it's worse than i thought. You have to enumerate all interfaces, and manually say you want to bind to them all.

Comment: on linux with Mono it is enough to bind to Any because that is "actually 0.0.0.0" and it means "all interfaces"...

Comment: Well, it means "all IPv4 interfaces", anyway.