# tcplistener bind all local address?

Tags: .net, sockets, tcplistener

I have a server app i'm playing with. I bind the address to 127.0.0.1 and it was fine until i wanted to connect from a client inside a VM. So i bind it to 192... Well now my test which all connect to 127... can't connect. I know i could use Any but i don't want the outside internet connecting (I know i could use firewalls but ATM i dont want to).

Is there a way i can specify any local address so 192.x.x.x and 127.0.0.3 work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When specifying your local address, use [IPAddress.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx) instead of an explicit address. See the previously answered question, too: [TcpListener: How to listen on specific port on all interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238096/tcplistener-how-to-listen-on-specific-port-on-all-interfaces)

Comment: If that host is accessible from outside, then yes. You could set up two TcpListeners, one for 192.x.x.x and another from 127.0.0.1.

Comment: How would i setup 192.x.x.x (and 127.x.x.x)?

Comment: @acidzombie24 see my previous comment. You would need 2 TcpListener objects, one for each ip address. Upon receiving an incoming request, send them to the same handler.