# How do I listen to multiple IPs with TcpListener?

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I have a TcpListener running on the local IP address but how do I get it to accept connections from all of the adapters? Because if I want to connect from the loopback(localhost) I can't.

Regards,
Jordan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To listen on all adapters/interfaces you will want to listen on 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking for IPAddress.Any to listen to all incoming connections or IPAddress.Loopback to listen to the loopback address.  If you want to listen for connections from specific IP addresses, I believe you have to create one socket for each incoming IP address.

Edit: 
... I may be misunderstanding your question.  The following link might help you out:
[TcpListener: How to listen on specific port on all interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238096/tcplistener-how-to-listen-on-specific-port-on-all-interfaces)

Comment: Just learned that "The Any field is equivalent to 0.0.0.0 in dotted-quad notation." according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx