# UDP receive delay in WinForms application, but not Console application

Tags: c#, winforms, network-programming, udp

I am currently writing a program that listens on UDP 67 (DHCP).  For some reason, there seems to be a delay of 1-2 minutes to receive datagrams - but only on WinForms.  When executing in a console applications, everything works as intended, with no noticeable delay ( < 10 seconds).  I'm using the identical code for each.

**Edit:** Also note, that sometimes the message doesn't come in for over 5 minutes.  Restart the program, it might come in.

**Second Edit:** Wireshark shows traffic coming in - but my application doesn't ever get it.

Any ideas?

Console Code:

```
    private const int listenPort = 67;
    private static void StartListener()
    {
        bool done = false;
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
        try
        {
            while (!done)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast");
                byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                int len = bytes.Length;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            listener.Close();
        }
    }
    public static int Main()
    {
        StartListener();
        return 0;
    }
```

WinForms Code:

```
    private const int listenPort = 67;
    public DHCPServer()
    {
        StartListener();
    }
    private void StartListener()
    {
        bool done = false;
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
        try
        {
            while (!done)
            {
                byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                int len = bytes.Length;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {   
        }
        finally
        {
            listener.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: 10 seconds already is a _very_ noticeable delay! How do you determine when exactly a message has arrived (I assume a breakpoint in the line that follows `Receive()`)?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - Yes, 10 seconds is a noticeably delay.  However, it is within reason for the DHCP process.  At least in my opinion.

Comment: @MikeChristiansen can you test your winforms code with `Task.Run(() => StartListener());`

Comment: @C.Evenhuis  Hmm.. Figured out that was not the issue.  My program is listening on the wrong network adapter.  Wireshark and the VM that I am using for ipconfig /renew are using "interface 5", and my program is using "interface  1" and "interface 6" (both for some reason, probably virtual switch and such).  Next question is how do I get my program to listen on the appropriate interface?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238096/tcplistener-how-to-listen-on-specific-port-on-all-interfaces

Comment: @SmackJack - Yeah, I tried that, didn't work.  I'm not worried about it right now...