# programmatically access different NICs when sending web request

Tags: c#, networking, system.net

hobbyist/non-profession programmer here. I don't have a strong grasp on network addressing.

I have a computer that simultainiously connects to two different networks. 1 through wireless, one by network cable.

In my DotNet (c#) windows form app, I would like it to send some requests to one of the networks through one of the NICs, and other requests through the other one.

How would I specify/set (some dotNet object property?) which network/NIC the request flows through?

Comment: Take a look here it's actually easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436778/send-broadcast-message-from-all-network-adapters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Socket.Bind() before connecting to specify a particular local endpoint before establishing the connection.  Depending on which of the 2 local ips you have you bind it should go through one interface or the other.

Comment: Thanks MK, that's what I got from Nissan Fan''s link too.